# JQuery - why doesn't form submit?

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

When the line below `$("#classList").submit();` gets hit, the form isn't submitting, the JavaScript just continues.  What am I missing?  I'm using JQuery mobile on the page (that's why there's a `data-ajax="false"` attribute on the form, to prevent a form submission by Ajax.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#filter").on("click", function () {
            if ($("#filter").val() == 'DONE') {
                $("#classList").submit();
            }
            $('#filterpanel').toggle();
            $("#filter").val(function (i, text) { return text == 'FILTER' ? 'DONE' : 'FILTER';});
       });
    });
</script>
<form id="classList" runat="server" data-ajax="false">
    <div class="search_field2">
        <input id="address" type="text" name="address" class="input12" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" data-role="none" />
        <span>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="" class="retina-sprite" data-role="none" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_box">
        <input id="filter" name="filter" type="button" value="FILTER" class="filter" data-role="none" />
    </div>
...
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the form method and action?

Comment: It's an ASP.net form.  If you specify an action attribute, it is ignored (the page will always post back to itself). If you omit the method attribute, it will be set to method="post" by default.  The JavaScript's finding the form although your question has made me wonder if it's got something to do with ASP.NET assigning a different ID to the form, which I'll look into

Comment: Nope, as expected the form ID is staying as specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have a input element with name `submit`, it overrides the forms submit method. Change the submit buttons name from submit to something else and it should work.

```
<form id="classList" runat="server" data-ajax="false">
    <div class="search_field2">
        <input id="address" type="text" name="address" class="input12" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" data-role="none" />
        <span>
            <input name="submits" type="submit" value="" class="retina-sprite" data-role="none" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_box">
        <input id="filter" name="filter" type="button" value="FILTER" class="filter" data-role="none" />
    </div>
...
</form>
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hwna2/2/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hwna2/)

Comment: Brilliant, that's the answer thanks!  Can't believe I've never come across this.  Would've been there for hours.